# Can I use my laptop as a monitor of PC using Ethernet LAN cable?

Tags: lan, remote, remote-control, remote-connection

I have a PC and a laptop . I want to control the PC by laptop's mouse and keyboard ! (no monitor & no mouse and keyboard for the PC)
And i want to do it only with LAN cable and without using Windows's "Remote Desktop Coneection" .
Is it possible ? Thank you ! :)

Comment: No; Its not possible

Comment: There's no need to downvote this question; it's concise (enough) and valid. The answer just happens to be no.

Comment: VNC? PCAnywhere?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No. You can't do that. Ethernet cable is not designed for that.

Comment: VGA over Ethernet does exist, though, as is HDMI over Ethernet. The cable doesn't care.

Comment: But according to his question, he is more likely to have pure ethernet connection, isn't it? And he want to use the keyboard and mouse from the laptop, but not using the screen.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to access the PC other than remote desktop.Then you can you VNC viewer to do the work. We can use other technologies like TeamViewer. You can even use Chrome Remote Desktop to access that machine.

Comment: Thanks ! I forgot to add extrA  explanations , cause I needed to control it for always even after restarting PC ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

i think this is what you need.
Extend your screen over network:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ahkyEmzMNSA

Comment: The idea is yo say something about it, like a review. Otherwise the answer is no better than googling.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1188956)